# Wrapping div to new line causing funny behavior

Tags: html, css, row

If any of the nested `div`s below have a length longer then an adjacent `div`, the `div`s don't wrap to the next line "properly".

Without dividing each row in it's own div, is there a way to force div #5 (in the example below) to fall underneath div `#1` even if `div` `#1` is taller than the rest?

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .video-item {
    margin: 10px 29px 20px 0px;
    width: 208px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
</style>

<div style="width: 948px;">
  <div class="video-item">1<br>This is what happens when Description is too long... </div>
  <div class="video-item">2<br>Description</div>
  <div class="video-item">3<br>Description</div>
  <div class="video-item">4<br>Description</div>
  <div class="video-item">5<br>Description</div>
  <div class="video-item">6<br>Description</div>
  <div class="video-item">7<br>Description</div>
  <div class="video-item">8<br>Description</div>
  <div class="video-item">9<br>Description</div>
  <div class="video-item">10<br>Description</div>
</div>
```

Example with even Description:
[image: Example with even Description]

Example with uneven Description:
[image: Example with uneven Description]

Comment: It's not a wierd behaviour, it's the way floating left div's stack. Imagine that they are tetris blocks not falling from top to bottom but from right to left. The ` 5 Description` block can't move left any further because 1 is too tall.

Comment: Give me a little arrow up then, it means the same :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `clear` CSS style on the div, to bring it back into normal flow:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .video-item {
        margin: 10px 29px 20px 0px; 
        width: 208px; 
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden; 
    }
    .clear {
        clear: left;
    }
</style>

<div style="width: 948px;">
    <div class="video-item">1<br>This is what happens when Description is too long...         </div>
    <div class="video-item">2<br>Description</div>
    <div class="video-item">3<br>Description</div>
    <div class="video-item">4<br>Description</div>
    <div class="video-item clear">5<br>Description</div>
    <div class="video-item">6<br>Description</div>
    <div class="video-item">7<br>Description</div>
    <div class="video-item">8<br>Description</div>
    <div class="video-item clear">9<br>Description</div>
    <div class="video-item">10<br>Description</div>
</div>
```

With CSS3, you could use `:nth-child` to achieve this more dynamically:

```
.video-item:nth-child(4n+1) {
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: Ack, it should be `nth-child(4n+1)` - only available in modern browsers though, so the initial solution is the one that should be used.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to force the height of your elements like this: (but @Pete solution is more elegant)

```
.video-item {
    margin: 10px 29px 20px 0px; 
    width: 208px; 
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden; 
    height: 70px;
}
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vk3x9/)